Make adjustments to the mobile view on the Product Listing Page
On the product listing page (category page), everything works well in the desktop view.
However, in the mobile view, I want to move the category-description div from the top to the bottom, positioning it just above the page-bottom div. Could you please advise me on how to achieve this? Thank you!
